# why Map<String, dynamic>.from((snapshot.data! as Event).snapshot.value) is giving an error says "Event" is not a type

Tags: flutter, firebase-realtime-database, flutter-streambuilder

```
StreamBuilder(
                       stream: reffVehicles.child('users').orderByKey().limitToLast(10).onValue,
                         builder: (context, snapshot){
                         final listtiles = <ListTile>[];
                         if(snapshot.hasData){
                           final vehicles = Map<String, dynamic>.from((snapshot.data! as Event).snapshot.value);
                           vehicles.forEach((key, value){
                             final nextVehicle = Map<String, dynamic>.from(value);
                             final vehicletile = ListTile(
                               title: Text(nextVehicle['car_name'].toString())
                             );
                             listtiles.add(vehicletile);
                           });

                         }
                         return ListView(
                           children: listtiles,
                         );
                         }
                     )
```

I'm expecting to get an array to iterate through and display its values through a `streambuilder`

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you're working from an outdated code sample, according to the [documentation of `onSnapshot`](https://pub.dev/documentation/firebase_database/latest/firebase_database/Query/onValue.html) its type is `DatabaseEvent` (instead of `Event` that you have now).